# Graded rings and isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $R$ and $S$ are graded rings, and $h_n:R_n\longrightarrow S_n$ is an isomorphism of groups for each $n$, then is $h$ a ring isomorphism in the natural way?

Thank you very much.

Comment: We can assume $h$ is a ring homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

If $h$ is a graded ring homomorphism to start with, then $h$ is an isomorphism iff $h_n$ are all isomorphisms of abelian groups.  But if $h_n$ are just random isomorphisms of abelian groups, there is no reason to say that they will together form a graded ring homomorphism.